# Shell script for searching custom search engine no longer works in Catalina (Ruby)

Tags: applescript, catalina, automator, search, ruby

I recently upgraded from Mac OS Mojave to Catalina. On Mojave, I used a quick action to perform web searches via Google's encrypted search engine at encrypted.google.com. The quick action script is `open "https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp')"`.

This script no longer works in Catalina due to deprecated Ruby support. Does anyone know how I could script the same action in Catalina?

Comment: You could install Ruby via Homebrew.

Comment: Or you could install Ruby via MacPorts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did eventually install Ruby via macports, but that, for some reason, didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have both the `applescript` and `automator` *tags* on your question, here is another approach using a **Run AppleScript** *action* in **Automator**...

I'd use '**Listing 32-7** AppleScriptObjC: Handler that URL encodes text' from [Encoding and Decoding Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/EncodeandDecodeText.html).

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

on run {input, parameters}
    open location "https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=" & encodeText(input as string)
end run

on encodeText(theText)
    set theString to stringWithString_(theText) of NSString of current application
    set theEncoding to NSUTF8StringEncoding of current application
    set theAdjustedString to stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding_(theEncoding) of theString
    return (theAdjustedString as string)
end encodeText
```